# View photos from firebase storage in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I've stored a set of pictures in firebase storage Manually  and I want Retrieving image and show them in list in Recycler View in android studio in java, I try many solution in this field but he is fail because  He did not display anything
and this code in onActivityCreated - fragment

```
StorageReference mStorageRef = getStorage().getReference();
            mStorageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
                for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                    if (prefix.getName().equals("1")) {
                        prefix.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult1 -> {
                            for (StorageReference item : listResult1.getItems()) {
                                item.getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(paths::add).addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                                    // Handle any errors
                                });
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Snackbar.make(recyclerView, getResources().getString(R.string.fail_show) + ": " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Snackbar.make(recyclerView, getResources().getString(R.string.fail_ID) + ": " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());
            /*mStorageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> paths.addAll(listResult.getItems()))
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Snackbar.make(recyclerView, getResources().getString(R.string.fail_show) + ": " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());*/
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 1);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new AdapterImageUploaded(requireContext(), paths);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(mAdapter.getItemCount());
```

this is adapter

```
public class AdapterImageUploaded extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterImageUploaded.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<byte[]> path_image;
    public Context context;

    public AdapterImageUploaded(Context context,ArrayList<byte[]> path_image) {
        this.path_image = path_image;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_upload_image, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(holder.item_upload).load(path_image.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.fish_2).into(holder.img_fish_uploaded);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return path_image.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView img_fish_uploaded;
        public ConstraintLayout item_upload;

        public MyViewHolder(ConstraintLayout linearLayout) {
            super(linearLayout);
            img_fish_uploaded = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_fish_uploaded);
            item_upload = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_upload);
        }
    }
}
```

**the problem is the code not show image in recyclerview **

Comment: So what the problem exactly, you don't know how to download images from firebase, or you don't know how to show them in recyclerview?

Comment: the problem is the code not show image in recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StorageReference mStorageRef = getStorage().getReference();
            mStorageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
                for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                    if (prefix.getName().equals("1")) {
                        prefix.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult1 -> {
                            for (StorageReference item : listResult1.getItems()) {
                                paths.add(item)
                            }
           RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 1);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new AdapterImageUploaded(requireContext(), paths);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(mAdapter.getItemCount());
                        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Snackbar.make(recyclerView, getResources().getString(R.string.fail_show) + ": " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Snackbar.make(recyclerView, getResources().getString(R.string.fail_ID) + ": " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```